# How to download products in a CSV file?

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, download

We are going to migrate our products to Shopify and we need to download the products in a CSV file? Is that possible?  How do you do that?

- using Porto theme

Comment: Magento has default funcnality of export CSV.

Comment: Did my answer solve your query? Please do accept the answer if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pawan mentioned magento has default functionality to export products as csv.

You can follow this link for procedure along with the options needed to do so -

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-exportimport-data-in-csv-files.html